# Equivalent of excel COUNTIFS

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am trying to get a COUNTIFS from excel type of result

Here is the products table:

**Name  Product**

```
john    car
john    football
john    image
max     food
max     tv
max     laptop
max     image
max     image
max     image
alex    tv
alex    laptop
alex    image
alex    cake
alex    cake
alex    cake
alex    cake
alex    car
```

The output should be:

**Name  Product Number of products per person   Number of products of the same type**

```
john    car     1   2
john    football1   1
john    image   1   5
max     food    1   1
max     tv      1   2
max     laptop  1   2
max     image   3   5
alex    tv      1   2
alex    laptop  1   2
alex    image   1   5
alex    cake    4   4
alex    car     1   2
```

Number of products per person is count of products by name by product
and Number of products of the same type is based on the total count by product

for example image is repeated 3 times for max so in col C the answer is 3 but it there 5 times in the table so answer in col D is 5

I tried but not getting the correct answer:

```
SELECT
  name,
  product,
  COUNT(*),
  COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY product),
from products
GROUP BY 1,2
ORDER BY 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are quite close.  You need to *sum* the `COUNT(*)`.  You can do this directly in the aggregation query:

```
SELECT name, product,
       COUNT(*),
       SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER (PARTITION BY product)
FROM products
GROUP BY 1, 2
ORDER BY 1
```

Comment: Many thanks Gordon! May I please ask why did COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY product) not work? I though this means count by product?

Comment: @userag123 . . . Because it counts *after* the aggregation.  So, it counts the number of rows in the result set with the product (regardless of `name`).  The `SUM()` is the `SUM()` of the aggregated `COUNT(*)` -- the sum of the third column.

Answer (score 1):

```
#standardSQL
SELECT name, product, product_per_person,
  SUM(product_per_person) OVER(PARTITION BY product) product_total
FROM (
  SELECT
    name,
    product,
    COUNT(*) product_per_person
  FROM `project.dataset.products`
  GROUP BY 1,2
)
ORDER BY 1
```

if to apply to your sample data  - result should be

```
Row name    product     product_per_person  product_total    
1   alex    cake        4                   4    
2   alex    car         1                   2    
3   alex    image       1                   5    
4   alex    laptop      1                   2    
5   alex    tv          1                   2    
6   john    car         1                   2    
7   john    football    1                   1    
8   john    image       1                   5    
9   max     food        1                   1    
10  max     image       3                   5    
11  max     laptop      1                   2    
12  max     tv          1                   2
```

Answer (score 0):

use group by name and product

```
  SELECT  name,
      product,    
      COUNT(*),    
      COUNT(*) OVER (partition by product)

    from products

    GROUP BY name,product

    ORDER BY 1
```